# Ajax Form Submit using jQuery 1.11.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
              resizable: false,
              height:250,
              width:530,
              modal: true,
              buttons: {
                "Save and Close": function() {
                    $('#frmSurvey').append("<input type='hidden' name='page' value='2' />");
                    var url = "save.php"; 

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: $("#frmSurvey").serialize(), 
                        success: function(result){
                            var language = $("#lang").val();
                            var json = $.parseJSON(result);
                                if(json.response.status == 'success') {
                                        window.location.replace("finish.php?l=" + language);

                                } else {
                                    alert(json.response.message);
                                }

                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                                        } else  if (jqXHR.status == 503) {
                                            alert('Error: ' + jqHXR.responseText);
                                        }else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                            alert('Internal Server Error. [500]');
                                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                            alert('Requested JSON parse failed');
                                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                            alert('Time out error');
                                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                            alert('Ajax request aborted');
                                        } else {
                                            alert('Uncaught Error.');
                                        }
                          }

                    });
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
              }
            });
          });
```

Running jQuery 1.11.2 but am getting the following `console` error message and I cannot fathom what is wrong:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

m.parseJSON @   jquery-1.11.2.js:4
$.ajax.success  @   validate_honeywell_v2.js:220
j   @   jquery-1.11.2.js:2
k.fireWith  @   jquery-1.11.2.js:2
x   @   jquery-1.11.2.js:4
b   @   jquery-1.11.2.js:4
```

220 =

```
var json = $.parseJSON(result);
```

Has jQuery changed how this is handled?

Comment: This is issue from backend. Check in **Network tab** of developer tool for full response. You are not getting JSON response from API.

Comment: Thanks - have checked: Method POST Status = 200 - nothing else showing in the Network tab.

Comment: Click on that request at right side there will come some tables like "Headers, Request, Response". By clicking on response you can see complete response.

Comment: Thanks again, yes, can see those, nothing in Red - Green and Orange - total duration something like 264ms

Comment: Can you see tabs Headers, Preview, Response after clicking on api call in network tab? Like this http://tr1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2015/05/07/7051a8b5-f4a7-11e4-940f-14feb5cc3d2a/02232012figure_j.gif

Comment: Using Chrome....hang on a sec, can't see those as per your screen shot.

Comment: Click on request then only you can see those tabs.

Comment: Got it - can now see the tabs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97602/discussion-between-homer-j-and-manwal).